# Checking if an ASP page is dirty before asking user if they want to leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET form and it has a bunch of user inputs, text boxes, checkboxes, etc. I need to be able to check if the user has made an edit on the form without saving and if so prompt then beforeunload.

I have a dirty flag that set once the user edits one of the text boxes. If they save the data on the form then I reset the flag. Therefore the flag should only ever be set when the user edits but has not saved.

I then use this flag to decide whether or not to prompt the user “Are you sure you want to leave this page?”

Code snippet:

```
var _isDirty = false;

    $(function () {
        try {
                $("#MainContent_txtSometextBox").change(function () {
                    _isDirty = true;
                });
            } catch (e) { }
        });
```

The problem is I don’t want to have to set this on every control. Is it possible to set it at a page level? I don’t think it will be that easy as we also have custom user controls on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a different selector

```
$("input, select, textarea").change(function () {
    _isDirty = true;
});
```

you may extend this as needed.

If you need to restrict it, wrap it in a `div`, then `find`.

```
$("#myForm").find("input, select, textarea").change(function () {
    _isDirty = true;
});
```

Comment: How would this work with elements added dynamically (through ajax or otherwise)? perhaps [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: @Daniel A. White Thanks - I did some "basic" testing with this implementation and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to target all input, textarea, select and button elements. For button you would need an on click event and for textboxes and areas, the dirty flag is triggered on loss of focus.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jarekb84/r2FjQ/1/)**

```
$('#body :input'​​​​​​​​).change(function () {
    _isDirty = true;
});
```